# How can I translate the Lambda operator functions in this C# example?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to understand this block of code:

```
List<string> selectedValues = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(li => li.Selected)
    .Select(li => li.Value)
    .ToList();
```

From my research I understand the point of the Lambda function (to provide a function that can be used as a parameter in-line) but why in this case is it being used?

To add only items to selectedValues that are li.Selected, and only add the value of those selected items to the list called selectedValues? If this is the case, is there no other more readable way to do so? How else could this be written? Is my understanding correct?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: is this not readable ?

Comment: Think of the lambda function parameter as a filter that gets applied to each element in the IEnumerable. If the function returns true then that item is included in the result.

Comment: To me, this is about as clear and concise as it gets. You might initially find LINQ opaque, but stick with it. It's a Good Thing, and understanding what it means to throw methods/lambdas around as parameters will change the way you think about programming... (and lead you write considerably less loops).

Comment: It can also be rewritten using the declarative Linq syntax, if that helps - `from item in CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>() where item.Selected select item.Value).ToList()`

Comment: I understand, and yes it is readable I just wanted to be sure I was understanding correctly. Thank you for your help everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block of code in questions does the following:

1. Get all items in `CheckBox1.Items`
2. Cast them to the type of `ListItem`
3. Filter for only the items that are selected
4. Select the value of those, now filtered, items.
5. Cast the result to a list.

You could also write the code as follows:

```
List<string> selectedValues = new List<string>();
foreach (object item in CheckBoxList1.Items) {
    var listItem = (ListItem)item;
    if (listItem.Selected) {
       selectedValues.Add(listItem.Value);
    }
 }
```

Comment: `(ListItem)item` should be `item as ListItem` to be safe from runtime null exception and then null check before doing anything on it

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: No, the opposite is true as i've commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442181/how-can-i-translate-the-lambda-operator-functions-in-this-c-sharp-example#comment95694150_54442359). This is closer to the LINQ approach. If you wanted it more readable you could use `foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)`, so cast with the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 3):

You did read the lambda correctly. lambda are easier to get if you think of it as a step by step execution. To me they are more readable and they are all coherent. They follow the same structure all the way while there are many ways to write the same thing, the lambda for this example will always be the same.

Another way to write it (note that here i code everything the lambda actually verifies) :

```
List<string> selectedValues = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count(); i++)
{
    ListItem item = CheckBoxList1.Items[i] as ListItem;

    if(item != null)
    {
        if(item.Selected == true)
        {
            selectedValues.Add(item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Nitpicking: this is not the same as the LINQ approach because you handle the case that there is something in the `ListItemCollection` that is not a `ListItem`. Then you skip it. The `Cast<ListItem>` would fail with an exception. Since `ListItemCollection` only contains `ListItems` the `Cast<ListItem>` will always work so your safe cast is unnecessary. It is necessary to use `Cast` because `ListItemCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<ListItem>` but only `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Rango `Cast` would fail, and `OfType` won't right?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: `OfType` is a filter + cast, so doesn't fail, similar to your try-cast-if

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `Cast` does not throw so it's either a `cast` wrapped in a `try...catch` or it does a ` obj as [type]` instead which is what i assumed as the value return null when you check and if it was a simple cast it would throw and exception. And as @Range said the `OfType` is a somewhat doing in the realm of `Where(o => o is [type]).Select(o => o as [type])`

Comment: @Rango Yes i totally agree with you. Hence why in my sample i mentioned that i wrote the way LINQ does. LINQ is generic and i doubt they hardcoded inside it something like "if it's a checklistbox and iterating on the items property they are all listitems so do the loop this way". I am pretty sure it does the same thing on a `List<Myclass>` than it does on a `List<object>`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty expressive about what it should do or doing.

Lambda expression is just a delegate pointing to an anonymous method which a method with body but it has no name using which it can be invoked.

When we write the following:

```
CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected)
```

Compiler would generate a method like following:

```
internal bool <M>b__0_0(ListItem x)
{
    return x.Selected;
}
```

and a delegate type to hold reference to that method :

```
public static Func<ListItem, bool> <>9__0_0;
```

and will call the method for each item in the collection.

We can rewrite the code without using lambda expression for understanding like :

```
public bool IsSelectedWhere(ListItem item)
{
    return item.Selected;
}

public object SelectValue(ListItem item)
{
    return item.Value;
}
```

and we can call like:

```
 CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(IsSelectedWhere)
.Select(SelectValue)
.ToList();
```

The benefit of lambda expression is that we don't need to define methods in the code and we just write them as expression and compiler takes care of generating a method and calling it using `Func<T>`.

Hope it helps to some extent.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the clarification and confirmation.